# Why my gradle file(project) look like this? Rest things are missing but code is working fine for me, but I want to add classpath to configure code

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

My gradle build(project) file has changed to this how to get default gradle build file back.

[image: 1]

I tried to change from documentation but facing issue.

Comment: On the top left side right above the **app**, Click on `Android` & Select `Project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is new in android studio

this file project level gradle build

you just go with this

In Gradle -> settings.gradle

here all plugins are define

Comment: Thanks Manudeep. please upvote is also to get helps others.